# ASP MVC redirect to error page from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple question. How to redirect from controller to custom error page with http status code?
For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   this.Redirect("Not found", 404); //redirect to my error page with code 404
}
```

Comment: just return the view,
  
   return View("view name");

Comment: Return `new HttpNotFoundResult()`, and then use the error handling built in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add this code in web.config file:-

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

Add below code in controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller{
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View("Error");
}
public ViewResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
    return View("NotFound");
}}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I did everything exactly as above except  instead of "NotFound" I used "Error404". The controller goes there but I got: Error/Error404?aspxerrorpath=/Dashboaord.

When I move Error404.cshtml out of the folder Error, it redirects to the generic error page.